# Did these events in 7th episode 2nd season of Netflix 'El Chapo' actually happen?

Tags: historical-accuracy, el-chapo

At the end of the 7th episode of the 2nd season of Netflix's *El Chapo* two events happen:

- Firstly Los Emes massacred multiple civilians and burned down a remote village leaving the message for El Chapo and the government.
- Following a presumable Sinaloa, an answer was shown in form of the corresponding massacre in a bar full of civilians.

As this show is loosely based on a real story did those specific events really happened? If yes, are there any sources indicating such turn of events?

Such events probably would make headlines and while I was able to find multiple atrocities done by cartels, especially Los Emes (which I presume to be infamous Los Zetas), I could not identify said events in any online available news.